# Metal oxide formation minimum temperature?

Tags: metal, temperature, alkali-metals, oxides

Is there such thing as minimum temperature for creation of metal oxide?

Let's say a highly reactive metal, lithium, comes into contact with solid oxygen at a cryogenic temperature of 20 Kelvin, would oxide form, or will lithium act more like a precious metal at these super cold temperatures and remain oxide free?

Comment: Since you are having reaction between solids, diffusion is the limiting factor affecting kinetics. I highly doubt at these temperatures it's substantial enough to make an observable oxide layer. Keep in mind that alkali metals also visibly react with ice only when they are pre-heated. If they are not causing ice melting, there is no reaction.

Comment: Then again, oxygen is a biradical and might well react with zero activation energy, and then...

Comment: @IvanNeretin. Will oxygen react with lithium or with iron at $20$ Kelvin ?

Comment: With iron, it doesn't react much even at room temperature. With lithium, I don't know what to expect.

Comment: @andelisk Ok, then I change my question to liquid oxygen at 60 Kelvin. Will it make the oxide then?

Comment: It may be rather quantitative than qualitative question: What rate of oxide creation would be enough to observe oxide creation ? //  Remember that individual atoms or molecules do not have temperature. Different temperature just means different statistical energy distribution. Lithium atoms and oxygen molecules with enough energy may react at any temperature.

Comment: @Poutnik Since velocity of atoms at given temperature has large random distribution, I think I made mistake by asking this question in terms of temperature. What I really want to know is how much electron volt quantity of energy is required to create the oxide, if there even is any energy barrier, I want to know if this reaction theoretically requires zero energy that means it can happen at 0.001 Kelvin.

Comment: Since there is need to break O2 molecule to form 2 oxide ions, it is not IMHO justified to expect near zero activation energy.

Comment: @Poutnik I thought that since lithium is so electropositive, it might tear the oxygen atom away. Or alternatively, 4 lithium atoms might connect with dioxygen without any oxygen splitting needed.  I was surprised before at quantum effects affecting chemistry so despite being aware of the o2 bond energy, I thought this question is worth asking.

Comment: @poutnik you may not need to break the oxygen-oxygen bond completely. Lithium can form a peroxide, even if this would be only metastable. Even so, formation of the peroxide ion still requires a reduction of bond order, so the activation energy is merely less instead of zero.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I am aware of peroxide,  I used context of oxide. Another possible factor for nonzero activation energy is electron work function within metallic structure.

Comment: If there was near zero energy barrier, oxide formation reaction rate constant would be (very)  roughly $k \approx a \cdot \sqrt{T}$, driven by thermal collision rate. I very doubt this is the case. Usually, T change by 10K causes reaction rate change by 2-4times. The above case would need 4 times higher T for 2 times faster rate.